# Unknown modifier '/' in ...? what is it?

Tags: php, regex, warnings, preg-match

When i wrote the following, i get such warning, and it doesn't match anything, but i'm sure, that `$row_search['content']` contains `$value`...

```
preg_match_all("/[^\s]*".preg_quote($value)."[^\s]*/iu", $row_search['content'], $final_matched);

WARNING:preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown modifier '/' in C:\xampp\htdocs\finance\search\search.php on line 82
```

why i get such warning message?

Thanks

Comment: what is the content of `$value` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume `$value` contains a slash `/`, which is not escaped by [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php):

> The special regular expression characters are: `. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -`

Pass the delimiter you use to the function:

```
preg_match_all("/[^\s]*".preg_quote($value, '/')."[^\s]*/iu", $row_search['content'], $final_matched);
//                                        ---^
```

or use another delimiter.

Answer (score 4):

You should change your [`preg_quote($value)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) into [`preg_quote($value, "/")`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to escape the delimiter too.

In your example if `$value` contains "(content/other)" it will be escaped as "(content/other)" and this in your regex will be `/[^\s]*\(content/other\)[^\s]*/iu` as you can see there is a / which will case your regex to crash. If you explicitly say that "/" is the delimiter then the regex will be `/[^\s]*\(content\/other\)[^\s]*/iu`

Answer (score 2):

`/` is not a PCRE metacharacter, so although you're using it as the delimiter in your regular expression, `preg_quote()` won't escape it because it doesn't *know* you're using it as the delimiter. You'll have to pass it in as the second parameter, as the rest have said, in order for it to be escaped too:

```
preg_match_all("/[^\s]*".preg_quote($value, '/')."[^\s]*/iu", $row_search['content'], $final_matched);
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify `/` as delimiter when using [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/preg_quote):

```
preg_match_all("~/[^\s]*~".preg_quote($value, '/')."[^\s]*/iu", $row_search['content'], $final_matched);
```

Otherwise a `/` in the value of `$value` will not get escaped.