# PHP preg_replace "unknown modifier"

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to use an array of regular expressions to find and replace within a string in PHP, however I'm getting the error `unknown modifier`. I'm aware this appears to be a popular issue, however I don't understand how to fix it in my scenario.

Here is my original regex pattern:

```
{youtube((?!}).)*}
```

I run the following code against it to escape any characters:

```
$pattern = '/' . preg_quote($pattern) . '/';
```

That returns the following:

```
/\{youtube\(\(\?\!\}\)\.\)\*\}/
```

However, when I run this pattern through `preg_replace` I get the following error:

```
Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Unknown modifier 'y' ...
```

Any idea what needs to be changed, and at what stage of the code I've show here?

Many thanks

**Edit 1**

As requested, here is the code I'm using:

```
$content = "{youtube}omg{/youtube}";
$find = array();
$replace = array();

$find[] = '{youtube((?!}).)*}';
$replace[] = '[embed]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=';
$find[] = '{/youtube((?!}).)*}';
$replace[] = '[/embed]';

foreach ( $find as $key => $value ) {
    $find[$key] = '/' . preg_quote($value) . '/';
}

echo preg_replace($find, $replace, $content);
```

Here's a [live example](http://ideone.com/0NkcaL)

Comment: No, why are you using `preg_quote` anyway. It's meant for literal string parts, but you already have a regex pattern.

Comment: mario, I think they tried isolating the cause that way. The fact that it *still* throws weird errors is interesting in itself.

Comment: @mario I'm using `preg_quote` to solve an earlier problem... but even without it, I get the same error.

Comment: Please post the actual code you are running. Because I don't get that exact error for `preg_match("/\{youtube\(\(\?\!\}\)\.\)\*\}/", "");` either, there's no error at all for the actual pattern and the escaped pattern.

Comment: can you post your preg_replace?

Comment: Please see *edit 1* in the original question

Comment: Then it's this after all: [Unknown modifier '/' in ...? what is it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3565615)

Comment: Oh ****! Oh no guys, I was thinking it was the very first `{youtube}` pattern, not the second. Sorry for being an idiot, @mario, many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change your Regex delimiter to something that's not used in the pattern, in this example I used `@` which works fine.

`preg_quote` only escapes `. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -`, so when using a non-escaped character in your pattern, but also as your regex delimiter, it's not going to work as expected. Either change the delimiter as above, or pass it into `preg_quote` explicitely as part of the [`preg_quote($str, $delimiter)` overload](http://php.net/preg_quote).

```
$content = "{youtube}omg{/youtube}";
$find = array();
$replace = array();

$find[] = '{youtube((?!}).)*}';
$replace[] = '[embed]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=';
$find[] = '{/youtube((?!}).)*}';
$replace[] = '[/embed]';

foreach ( $find as $key => $value ) {
    $find[$key] = '@' . preg_quote($value) . '@';
}

echo preg_replace($find, $replace, $content);
```

Comment: Hi Rudi, long time no speak... how's things? Thanks for you (and @mario) for pointing this issue out, with `preg_quote` it failed to do the replace, however removing this does now work.

Comment: It is not always easy to choose delimiter that is not in the pattern, especially when pattern is calculated at run time.  Better way is to use standard delimiter `'/'` and pass it to `preg_quote` as second argument, so `preg_quote` will quote it along with other special characters.  See my answer for code example.

Comment: @ilmv - Things are good, how're your things? Should email me and catch up :D

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov It's not calculated at runtime, and I also mentioned to use the other overload.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass delimiter as second parameter for `preg_quote` like this:

```
$find[$key] = '/' . preg_quote ($value, '/') . '/';
```

Otherwise, delimiter will not be quoted and thus will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

I may be sat in a hospital waiting room away from a computer, but what you're doing seems to have way over complicated the problem.

If I am to understand this correctly, you want to replace some like this:

```
{youtube something="maybe"}http://...{/youtube}
```

With:

```
[embed]http://...[/embed]
```

No?

If that's the case the solution is as simple as something along the lines of:

```
preg_replace('#{(/?)youtube[^}]*}#', '[\1embed]', $content);
```

The important considerations being the preservation of the open/closed-ness of the tags, and wrapping the regex in something that doesn't conflict quite so much with your target string, in this case, hashes.

Comment: preg_replace_all may be necessary to ensure you capture all of the tags rather than only the first.